# How can I get Visual Studio 2005 to show my running JavaScript files in the Script Explorer?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2005

In the question [Why will Visual Studio 2005 not debug my javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/705254/why-will-visual-studio-2005-not-debug-my-javascript) I learned that **debugging is possible in Visual Studio 2005** but you have to start debugging your application and then press **CTRL-ALT-N to open the Script Explorer** to set break points, etc.

However, even with the following simple code, when I press CTRL-ALT-N, the **Script Explorer window is totally blank**. According to all the articles I have found on the subject, it should have e.g. in my case "main.js" (I imagine it is like debugging in Firebug) but it is blank.

**What else do I have to do to Visual Studio 2005 so that the Script Explorer shows my running javascript files?**

**Default.aspx:**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="TestJavascriptDebugging2005._Default" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <p>This is HTML and <script type="text/javascript">test()</script>.</p>
    <p><button onclick="doIt(this)">Test</button></p>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**javascript/main.js:**

```
function test() {
    document.write("this is from javascript code2");
}

function doIt(element) {
    alert("This is the javascript function2.");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try attaching your Visual Studio to MSIE via Debug > Attach to process (not sure if it is there in VS2005, look around).

When attaching to process make sure that you check script option.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to get started is:

- Open IE7
- Goto the menu Internet Options > Advanced
- Uncheck "Disable script debugging"

To add a break point in a javascript add "debugger;" in your code.  Open a page that references that script in IE7, and a popup will come up asking you if you want to debug your script in Visual Studio

```
<script type="text/javascript">

debugger;

// put your code here

</script>
```